# The method getHealth() is ambiguous for the type Player - Bukkit 1.6.4

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, ambiguous

This is a piece of my code for a plugin.

```
public boolean reapSoul(Player player, Player tplayer, double damage)
{
    if(player.hasPermission("myrace.wraith.reap"))
    {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "You have reaped " + tplayer.getName() + "'s soul.");
        damage = player.getLevel()/10;
        double heal = damage/2;
        tplayer.damage(damage);
        player.setHealth(player.getHealth() + heal);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am aware there are probably a lot of errors, and I can deal with them on my own. The one that I cannot deal with is

```
player.setHealth(player.getHealth() + heal);
```

Eclipse (my IDE) tells me that the method getHealth() is ambiguous for the type Player.

I am aware that this is probably a really popular question since the release of Bukkit 1.6.x but none of the searches I did gave me a solution I could understand.

If [this](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/oops-i-didnt-break-your-plugins-ambiguous-gethealth.156975/) is indeed the solution could you please help me understand what I can do...

Thank-you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try double `h = player.getHealth()`? From what I understand there are two getHealth methods because of backwards compatibility. There is probably some reflection magic to figure out whether the new (type double) or the old (type int) is requested.

Likewise setHealth has two versions so the compiler cannot figure out whether it should cast `getHealth() + health` to int and use `setHealth(int)` or whether it should cast`getHealth() + health` to double and use `setHealth(double)` because `getHealth()` is ambigious.

@Yourcomment
It is deprecated but still supported for backwards compatibility, at this point I am clueless as to why this would happen, seems bukkit has a complicated build procedure with its jars so something might have gone wrong there, however a solution I found on [google](https://forums.bukkit.org/threads/ambiguous-gethealth.176704/) suggests that casting the player to Damageable gets rid of the problem.

```
Damageable d = (Damageable) player;
```

Comment: I did what you told me to do, but no success.

`double playerHealth = player.getHealth()` I still get the same error.

Comment: Is it still getHealth that is ambigious?

Comment: Yup, `getHealth()` is still ambiguous. I know there are two methods `getHealth()`, one deals with `int` and the other with `double`. I believe the one that deals with integers is deprecated though...

Comment: Damageable d = (Damageable) player; worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but I think you might need to explicitly cast to a type:

```
double playerHealth = (double)player.getHealth();
player.setHealth(playerHealth + heal);
```

Comment: This wouldn't explain the compiler warning saying that `getHealth` is ambiguous... which it actually is: the API was changed so `getHealth` used to return `int` but now it returns `double`. They kept both for compatibility (don't know how though, nor how to bypass it).

Comment: Ah, should have read the question more carefully - thanks. I don't know how they've managed it, either. I've updated my answer with a guess at how to rectify it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is more than one getHealth().  Java cannot figure out which you are referring to because they are both valid in the context that you are using it in.

If the first responders answer does not work you can also do...

```
player.setHealth(new Double(player.getHealth()) + heal);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I found a simple solution for it. Only you need to use some Reflections:
You can get the health in double, but also in int:

```
Player j;   
int health_in_int=(int)j.getClass().getMethod("getHealth", double.class).invoke(j);
double health_in_double=(double)j.getClass().getMethod("getHealth", double.class).invoke(j);
```